# Can't get Geckofx to work

Tags: c#, xulrunner, gecko, geckofx

How do I set up GeckoFX in Visual Studio 2013?

I downloaded the GeckoFS files from https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-29.0/downloads and tried to add `Geckofx-Core.dll` and `Geckofx-Winforms.dll` to components in c#. That worked and I created a browser in a form but when running it I got this error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException' occurred in Geckofx-Core.dll

Additional information: Unable to load DLL 'xul': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

I tried adding various versions of `xulrunner` to the project like version 22 and 29 but that didn't remove the error.

All I would like to do is make a simple windows form application that opens a GeckoFX browser using the latest GeckoFx-29.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you need to download either xulrunner 29 or Firefox 29.

The you need to call `Xpcom.Initialize(path)` when path is the folder of the installed xulrunner 29 or Firefox 29.

For example If you installed Firefox 29 to "c:\program Files x86\Mozilla Firefox\"

Then you would call `Xpcom.Initialize(@"c:\program Files x86\Mozilla Firefox\")`

This tells geckofx where to find xul.dll.

Then you can use the GeckoWebBrowser control in your winforms application.

Note - you should also ensure that your Main entry point has the `[STAThread]` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this error is caused because of I initialised `xulrunner` in `Form1_Load` function. I resolved it by initialising `xulrunner` in  `public Form1()` function.